# Redshift unload's file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm running a Redshift unload command, but am not getting the name I desire.  The command is:

```
UNLOAD ('select * from foo')
                 TO 's3://mybucket/foo'
                 CREDENTIALS 'xxxxxx'
                 GZIP
                 NULL AS 'NULL'
                 DELIMITER as '\t'
                 allowoverwrite
                 parallel off
```

The result is mybucket/foo-000.gz.  I don't want the **slice number** to be the end of the file name (it'd be great if it can be eliminated completely), I want to add a **file extension** at end of the file name.  I'd like to see either of the following:

- mybucket/foo-000.txt.gz
- mybucket/foo.txt.gz

Is there any way to do this (without writing a lambda post process renamer script)?

Comment: Have you tried using `PARALLEL OFF`? Also, note that there is a maximum file size so if your data is too big, it will still create multiple files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TL;DR**
No.

**Explanation:**
As it says in [Amazon Redshift UNLOAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) document, if you do not want it to be split into several parts, you can use `PARALLEL FALSE`, but it is strongly recommended to leave it enabled. Even then, the file will always include the `000.[EXT]` suffix (when the `[EXT]` exists only when the compression is enabled), because there is a limit to a file size that Redshift can output, as says in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html#unload-parallel):

> By default, UNLOAD writes data in parallel to multiple files,
>   according to the number of slices in the cluster. The default option
>   is ON or TRUE. If PARALLEL is OFF or FALSE, UNLOAD writes to one or
>   more data files serially, sorted absolutely according to the ORDER BY
>   clause, if one is used. The maximum size for a data file is 6.2 GB.
>   So, for example, if you unload 13.4 GB of data, UNLOAD creates the
>   following three files.
>
> ```
> s3://mybucket/key000    6.2 GB 
> s3://mybucket/key001    6.2 GB
> s3://mybucket/key002    1.0 GB
> ```

Therefore, it will alway add at least the prefix `000`, because Redshift doesn't know what size of the file he is going to output in the first place, so he's adding this suffix in case the output will reach the size of 6.2 GB.

If you ask why the use of `PARALLEL FALSE` is not recommended, I'll try to explain it in several points:

1. The most important reason is because of the way a Redshift cluster designed. Each cluster includes at least 2 servers, when one of them is a leader node and the rest are data nodes. The purpose of leader node, is to control the data nodes, it hold the necessary information to work with all data in Redshift, either read or write.
   When you unload data from Redshift while the flag `PARALLEL` is `TRUE`, it will create at least X files, when X is the number of nodes you choose to construct the Redshift cluster of, in the first place. It means, that the data is written directly from the data nodes themselves, which is much faster because it's doing it in parallel and skips the leader node.
   When you decide to turn this flag to off, all data is gathered from all of the data nodes into a single node, the leader node, because it needs to reorganize the sorting of the rows to output and also compress it if needed as a single stream. This action causes you data to be written much slower.
2. Also, this is significantly decreases Redshift cluster performance in a matter of reading and writing data, because everything (read and write queries) goes through the leader node, and as it says above, when the leader node is overloaded, there will be a performance issue.
   The queries `COPY` and `UNLOAD` work directly with the data nodes, therefore, they behave almost the same way as if you would use `PARALLEL TRUE`. In the contrary, queries like `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT`, are processed by the leader node, that's why they suffer from the leader node loads.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  The consumers of my exports requested a single file as their export, but you raise some issues I/they didn't consider regarding file size limits.

Comment: See no reason that the onload could not have a feature to 'remove suffix on one file output'

Comment: Even on providing extension explicitly, I see no reason why instead of file being generated as `s3://mybucket/key.csv000`
it could not be `s3://mybucket/key000.csv`

Comment: Does anyone able to name a single file export without 000?