# Redshift Unload to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, unload

I'm not sure how to unload a table to S3 bucket in a csv.gz format.

the full path should look like this:
S3://bucket-name/prod/del/table_name/table_name__YYYYMMDD.csv.gz

This is the code I have now but it's only storing the files as 000.gz

````
``` unload ('select * from (select * from table_name)') to 'S3://bucket-name/prod/del/table_name/'
   iam role '........'
   partition_by (date)
   ALLOWOVERWRITE 
   delimiter '|' 
   CSV 
   GZIP 
   PARALLEL OFF 
   HEADER;
````

```
    
Can someone point me to the right direction?
Thanks,
Rosa
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redshift unload's file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255954/redshift-unloads-file-name)

Comment: the resultant output of the query pasted matches the parameters of what is being specified in `unload` command so if you want to include the table name then you can change path as `S3://bucket-name/prod/del/table_name/table_name_` , if your table name is `foo_bar` then file name would be `foo_bar_00.csv.gz`

Comment: what about if i need my file name to bee foo_bar__date=YYYYMMDD.csv.gz?

Comment: No can do.  Redshift always defines the file names to be able to write multiple objects in S3.  So it has file name extensions on the file names to avoid name collisions.  Even with "Parallel Off" Redshift may need to make more than 1 file if the size of the first object is greater than MAXFILESIZE parameter (defaults to 6.2GB for S3 efficiency).  No matter what you set this too there is always a possibility to make a file bigger.